# What are the best weights after training a model? Lowest loss? Validation loss?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm using Keras to solve a regression task. There, the options for saving the model weights are:

1. Use the model weights at the end of the training procedure (for me: early stopping if loss didn't improve for ten epochs),
2. use the weights that produced the best loss or
3. use the weights what produced the best validation loss.

If I select the model weights based on the validation loss, my results will be biased towards the validation set. But then again, same goes for the training set. 
I could also save all of the above weights and test which one performs best on a test set - which produces a bias towards the test set. So which one to use?

This questions seems really basic to me but unfortunately, I wasn't able to find an answer for myself. If there is an article about that which I miss, feel free to just post the link instead of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose people usually choose a model with the best validation performance, and then evaluate the model performance on test set.  While the model selection may potentially introduce bias towards the validation set, the test set provides an unbiased evaluation of the model performance for unseen data.

I think this scikit-learn page provides a concise explanation of the concept.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

If I remember correct, Andrew Ng's machine learning course covers the topic as well. https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning